# how can I deserialize map to different property name

Tags: serialization, json.net

my JSON string is like this.

```
string jsonstring1 = @"{'data':'N'}";
string jsonstring2 = @"{'data':[{'name':'jack','address':'la'}]}";
string jsonstring3 = @"{'data':{'flag':true}}";
```

how to define a class which can be used by those three JSON string deserialize to object?

Comment: Use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that these three are your only possible JSON strings, you need to create three root classes. You can do this using some [tools](http://json2csharp.com/) or simply by copying each of your JSON strings and pasting them by going to Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes in Visual Studio. For instance the classes corresponding to jsonstring2 will look like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Person[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to detect the type of "data" like follows:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonstring2);
string type = jo["data"].GetType().Name;
```

which in this case will be JArray (the other two are JValue and JObject). Then you can deserialize the string to the correct class by using a switch statement.